# Question I just asked shows up in "Active" but not "Newest"?

Tags: support

I just asked a [wiki question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22324/has-it-been-a-year-already), and it showed up immediately when I click the "Active" tab under Questions. However, when I click the "Newest" tab, it didn't for a couple minutes. Is this a caching thing or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Newest' tab seems to be cached more heavily than 'Active' (and the main page too).  The same always happens to me as well.